# Calculating Steam Inventory Value

Tags: api, steam, calculation, price, inventory

I don't have problem with getting inventory items. But I can't calculate items prices efficiently.
Valve doesn't have an api for prices.

What i have tried (using "steamcommunity.com") (javascript for example):

```
itemHashNameArray.forEach((hashname) => {

    let url = `https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/&appid=730&market_hash_name=${hashname}`;

    let itemDetails = steamApi(url); 
    //"steamApi" function just sends get request to site and returns response as json.
    
    let itemPrice = parseFloat(itemDetails.lowest_price.split(" ")[0].replace(",", "."));

            })
```

"steamcommunity.com/market" allows you to get 1 item price per request.
It is very slow / not efficient. Also steam blocks you after so many request.

Third partie apis that I found, allows 1 item per request too.
And they don't even support other currencies except dollar.
I need to calculate for other currencies too.

Is there faster and better way/api?

Comment: Need some clarification...it looks like you are querying the site directly? Not using a dedicated API service? I don't think Valve itself has one but there may be third parties. And yes, any regular website will probably limit requests since that is a strain on usage and costs.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify what's going on:

Most webpages and APIs have limits as far as requests, this helps prevent malicious DoS attacks or simply too much of a resource drain (often costly too). I've ran into this trouble with trying to pull Wikipedia/DBPedia information.

While this is annoying, often times a company or a third-party will recognize the need for doing bulk transactions against their data, and open up an API (usually for a fee): https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/gettingstarted

Some third parties include [SteamApis](https://steamapis.com/) and [Steamlytics](http://csgo.steamlytics.xyz/).

There is a whole subreddit dedicated to this too, here's a relevant post for the API call to get all of a user's inventory items: https://www.reddit.com/r/SteamBot/comments/jey4sg/help_i_am_trying_to_make_a_script_that_counts_the/

*Potentially* another option is to roll-your-own API service, which could somehow pull inventory data at a rate that doesn't hit limits. Not sure of the legality of this or what kind of hoops third parties have had to jump through, and it would be the most costly probably unless you start charging for its usage. I think loading the full html and then writing a parser to dissect some of that information with straight Javascript or JQuery would alleviate some of the calls looking like spam, but that probably has a limit too and I'm unsure that would include all of the relevant information easily available.